# Tensorflow prints the same info twice while training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a model for object detection using tensorflow.. and while training, in the terminal, tensorflow prints the same info twice as follows :

```
INFO:tensorflow:global step 3292: loss = 3.2832 (2.960 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 3292: loss = 3.2832 (2.960 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 3293: loss = 3.5285 (3.675 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 3293: loss = 3.5285 (3.675 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 3294: loss = 2.3972 (3.564 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 3294: loss = 2.3972 (3.564 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 3294.
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 3294.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0.294019
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0.294019
```

I noticed this "issue" only while training using tensorflow installed from source, I trained two models using tensorflow installed using pip and the logging was normal. I don't see any side effect of this behavior but I'm curious about what's causing it. Any idea?

Comment: Did you train the exact same model (and code) on both versions of tensorflow? Because if not i'm guessing the bug is in your code not in tensorflow

Comment: well, I'm training to get the same network I had but using a different model (checkpoint) I used an ssd_mobilenet_v1 and now I'm using the newer version of it ssdlite_mobilenet_v2 and I didn't change anything from the code source in both cases only of course the configuration file.

Comment: If it's happening in the same code only in specific versions of tensorflow I would file a bug report, but that assumes there's no bug in your code and that I can't know

Comment: thanks for the tip I'll do that.. is it possible that this can impact the training ? or is it just visual ? I just upgraded my tensorflow (the one with pip installation) to match the tensorflow installed from source and launched a training session just to check if it was from the version but the logging problem didn't appear :/

Comment: This thread mentions this behavior: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8023

Answer (score 2):

Open `variables_helper.py` in m`odels/research/object_detection/utils/variables_helper.py` and change `import` like this：

```
import re
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import logging as logging
slim = tf.contrib.slim
```

and it is solved.